# How do I add a boolean OR to cognito-idp list-user's --filter option

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-cli

Currently, I can get a user in the user pool by specifying their username like so:

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id  xxx --filter 'username="ABC"'
```

However, what do I do if I want to get both user "ABC" and user "DEF"? Is it possible to add a boolean OR to the filter string?

Something like

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id  xxx --filter 'username="ABC" or username="DEF"'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [jmespath](https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/07/27/advanced-aws-cli-jmespath-query/) in the query parameter instead of `--filter`, the syntax for multiple values is

```
[? expr1 || expr2]
```

So you can use

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id  us-west-demo --query 'Users[?Username==`demo1` || Username==`demo2`]'
```

[AmazonCognito-list-users](https://github.com/Adiii717/aws-cli-cheatsheet/tree/master/AmazonCognito)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the --query option!

I did find out something strange though, if i query for users with a username of "SG125387" or "0125387", the query works.

However, if i query for a username of "125387", the query does not work.

All 3 users, SG125387, 0125387 and 125387 do, of course, exist in my user pool.

This does not work: **aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id  xxx--query 'Users[?Username==`125387`]'**


This works: **aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id  xxx--query 'Users[?Username==`0125387`]'**

Answer (score 1):

this command working. i use single quote in filter object

```
aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id ap-southeast-AAAAAAAA  --limit 20 --region ap-southeast-1 --filter 'preferred_username="tserensodnom.t@gmail.com"'
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?