# Is there possibility to filter users by email's domain in Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I'm trying to list all of users in cognito using filter. I want to get only these users whose emails end with "gmail.com". I found [this topic](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3147) on github which seems pretty similar to what I'd like to achieve but no success here. Cognito doesn't have filtering other than exact match (f.e. username="test") and prefix (f.e. username^="test"). Did anyone face this kind of problem?

This is what I'm using: [API ListUsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html)

Here's my request using AWS CLI:

`aws cognito-idp list-users --user-pool-id eu-central-****** --filter "username ^= \"what.supposed.to.be.here?\""`

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62975216/14843902) you looking for?

Comment: Thanks for comment! Yes, it may work but I have tested it and these queries take a lot of time. However, my problem is the thing that I don't want to fetch all users and the filter them because it lasts too much - so given solution won't work :(

Answer (score -1):

To me seems the --filter has limit on that, You could try with

```
 --query "[?contains(not_null(email,''),'gmail.com')]" --all
```