# Is there a way to filter by multiple emails when using AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.ListUsersAsync from AWS SDK for dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use the ListUsersAsync (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentityProvider/MCognitoIdentityProviderListUsersAsyncListUsersRequestCancellationToken.html) to retrieve a list from AWS Cognito using AWS SDK for .NET

The problem is that I want to retrieve some specific users which I can filter by their emails.

```
public async Task<ListUsersResponse> ListUsers(int limit, List<string>? emails = null)
{
  var request = new ListUsersRequest
  {
    Limit = limit,
    UserPoolId = _configuration["AWS:Cognito:UserPoolId"].ToString()
  };

  if (emails != null && emails.Count > 0)
  {
    var filter = "email =";

    for (var i = 0; i < emails.Count - 1; i++)
    {
      filter += $"\"{emails[i]}\" || ";
    }
    filter += $"\"{emails.Last()}\"";

    request.Filter = filter; //filter = "email=\"email1@example.com\" || \"email2@example.com\"" 
  }

  return await _amazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.ListUsersAsync(request);
}
```

This returns an error : Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.

Is there a way to filter by multiple emails? I've not seen any multiple values example in the docs.

I'm aware that a --query option is possible for the CLI. ([How do I add a boolean OR to cognito-idp list-user's --filter option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62966866/how-do-i-add-a-boolean-or-to-cognito-idp-list-users-filter-option))

Is there any way to achieve the same for the SDK?